# Ассоциация файлов с jar

Tags: java, jar

Здравствуйте, волнует такой вопрос...

Можно ли ассоциировать файл некоторого формата (в частности собственный формат) с java программой? Т.е.чтобы по двойному клику на файл он открывался в java программе?

Answer (score 1):

[Setting .JAR File Association](http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.ru/2005/10/setting-jar-file-association.html)